# Download file from HTTP2 using axios nodejs in GKE

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, axios, google-kubernetes-engine, http2

I have deployed my NodeJs application on Google Kubernetes Engine. It is working fine with image download for other servers but with `images.asos-media.com` it is not working and give me a timeout error.
If I remove timeout then this download process never ends and hangs inside my application.
I debug and found that this `images.asos-media.com` is using `HTTP/2`.

But strange thing is that when I run my container in local it is working fine and only failed within GKE Cluster.

```
    import fs from 'fs';
    import path from 'path';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const downloadImage = async (url, destination) => {
      const dirPath = path.dirname(destination);
      if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dirPath, { recursive: true });
      }
    
      const writer = fs.createWriteStream(destination, { resumable: false });
      const response = await axios.get(url, {
        responseType: 'stream',
        timeout: 1 * 60 * 1000,
      });
      response.data.pipe(writer);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writer.on('finish', resolve);
        writer.on('error', reject);
      });
    };
    
    downloadImage('http://images.asos-media.com/products/flynn-skye-printed-tea-dress/7862151-1-eveningcuts?$XXL$&wid=513&fit=constrain', '/usr/src/app/test.jpg').then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: It is a console application running as a consumer.